# F#: Can't hide a type abbreviation in a signature? Why not?

Tags: f#

In F#, I'd like to have what I see as a fairly standard Abstract Datatype:

```
// in ADT.fsi
module ADT
  type my_Type

// in ADT.fs
module ADT
  type my_Type = int
```

In other words, code inside the module knows that my_Type is an int, but code outside does not. However, F# seems to have a restriction where type abbreviations specifically cannot be hidden by a signature. This code gives a compiler error, and the restriction is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

If my_Type were instead a discriminated union, then there is no compiler error. My question is, why the restriction? I seem to remember being able to do this in SML and Ocaml, and furthermore, isn't this a pretty standard thing to do when creating an abstract datatype?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Ganesh points out, this is a technical limitation of the F# compiler (and .NET runtime), because the type abbreviation is simply replaced by the actual type during the compilation. As a result, if you write a function:

```
let foo (a:MyType) : MyType = a + 1
```

The compiler will compile it as a .NET method with the following signature:

```
int foo(int a);
```

If the actual type of the abbreviation was hidden from the users of the library, then they wouldn't be able to recognize that the `foo` function is actually working with `MyType` (this information is probably stored in some F#-specific meta-data, but that is not accessible to other .NET languages...).

Perhaps the best workaround for this limiation is to define the type as a single-case discriminated union:

```
type MyType = MT of int
let foo (MT a) = MT(a + 1)
```

Working with this kind of type is quite convenient. It adds some overhead (there are new objects created when constructing a value of the type), but that shouldn't be a big issue in most of the situations.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Tomas and Ganesh also.

I now understand the issue, and I can see that, given this compilation strategy, this issue is a consequence. 

It's a little disappointing since I am working almost entirely in the F# space but I know interoperability is very important, so I won't complain! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Type abbreviations in F# are compiled away (i.e. the compiled code will use `int`, not `MyType`), so you can't make them properly abstract. In theory the compiler could enforce the abstraction within the F# world, but this wouldn't be very helpful as it would still leak in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can define a type abbreviation as private within a module:

```
// File1.fs
module File1
    type private MyType = int 
    let e : MyType = 42
    let f (x:MyType) = x+1

// Program.fs
module Program
do printfn "%A" (File1.f File1.e)
```

I am unclear why you can't hide it with a signature; I logged a bug to consider it.

Comment: True, but the sense in which I am imagining an ADT allows clients to know about the type, just not its representation.

If I have another function in File1,
let empty () : MyType = 1

Can I call this function from outside of File1 and pass its result to f?

Comment: Yes (I edited example above).  But I see your point, this is klutzy, as e.g. File1.MyType does not appear as an entity in the intellisense list, though File1.MyType does appear in the signatures of f and e.

Comment: Note that this does not prevent you from doing something like `File1.f 42` from outside the module, so the information that `MyType = int` isn't really hidden. So sadly this does not achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand F# does not allow an abbreviation to be hidden by a signature.

I found this [link](http://blog.matthewdoig.com/?p=134) where the blogger commented on this but I am not sure on the specifics of why this is the case.

My assumption is that this is a restraint set to allow more effective interop with other languages on the CLR.